# Shortcut for conditional formatting in Excel 2011 in OS X

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, shortcut

How do I create a keyboard shortcut for conditional formatting for Excel 2011 in OS X? I am unable to find any such shortcut.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Could you explain how I can do so? I am not familiar with them

Answer (score 1):

press **Alt + O + D** and In the New Formatting Rule dialogue box, select the option '**Use a formula to determine which cells to format**'. Set the format that you want to apply to the cells that are blank or have errors.

[image]

Comment: Please could you [edit] in a source for quoted content, and include text as text instead of an image as it cannot be read by screen readers or search.

Comment: This shortcut is a legacy shortcut for Excel 2010 and above in Windows (so that shortcuts from the pre-ribbon days could be used in newer versions). It doesn't apply to the Excel version for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the build in Recorder in Excel 2011. It is called Macro recorder.

Under Tools select New Macro recording. It will record your actions that you can call up with a keyboard short cut that you have chosen.

[image: keyboard shortcut]

[image: Macro]

The result would be something like this pending what you did, and you can recall that any time with your assigned keyboard shortcut.

[image: macro result]

Comment: But this fixes the rows/cells on which the formatting would be applied. For example, I would like to highlight duplicate selection on rows which I select. I need to repeat this process on different sets of rows. How can I do that?

Comment: It is meant for repetitive process, it will record your doing, so next time you can use the Macro recording to repeat it. In your case you could have Macro for one set named Macro 1, then have another one named Macro 2 and so on. It will record anything you do, just try it. Or you can do it in one Macro recording, first you select a set of cells (rows) and do conditional, then you select next set of rows and do conditional again.